# Redis - store and get limited keys with details

Tags: java, redis

I have a large number of objects per category.

I want to put all these objects with keys as category
then i want to fetch details of first 4 objects from this key and then next four like as in pagination.

For this i am trying to store all objects ids with category as key using hkeys

Putting all obejctids in hset:

```
 hset mycategory objectdid1 "objectdid1"
 hset mycategory objectdid2 "objectdid2"
 hset mycategory objectdid3 "objectdid3"
```

Putting all objectid details in hmset:

```
hmset objectdid1 title "george"
hmset objectdid2 title "george1"
hmset objectdid3 title "george2"
```

Getting hkeys:

```
hkeys mycategory
```

I am trying to get first 2 keys then next 2 as want to run a pagination. Also is there any other way i can achieve this whole thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What i believe is you need to use the [scan](http://redis.io/commands/scan) feature of redis

For your hashset you need to be using the [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) specifically.

Just be sure that count only controls the behaviour, you can also get 0 keys when call for scan, therefore only consider the scan iteration reset when the cursor returned is 0

For more info check the scan documentation link i have attached .

Sample code

```
ScanParams params = new ScanParams();
params.count(2);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  jedis.hset("foo", "a" + i, "a" + i);
}

ScanResult<Map.Entry<String, String>> result = jedis.hscan("foo", SCAN_POINTER_START, params);

assertFalse(result.getResult().isEmpty());
```

Taken from [Jedis Tests](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/50822a68188c706029fa46b3efb732565fea7e2b/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/commands/HashesCommandsTest.java)

Comment: i am using jedis to get the same executed from java , but scan is not available for version < 2.8 , and i didnt find an jedis version > 2.7 . so how  can i use jedis with scan option

Comment: Instead of realease you could maybe pick the latest version from github, Check this: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/521

Comment: By the last comment, it should have been released

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal Check the hscan function https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/50822a68188c706029fa46b3efb732565fea7e2b/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/commands/HashesCommandsTest.java

Comment: hi basit , i dont want all keys but want first 3 keys then next 3 keys and so on  , hscan dont have such option to control limit as redis sort. please suggest to achieve this..thanks

Comment: yeah, check the hcount function. Count ensures a limitation on keys. You'll either get 3 keys or less (upto 0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to both store serialized objects in hashes and add these object identifiers in sorted sets or lists, and then use `zrange` or `lrange` respectively to get paginated identifiers, and then pass them to a `hmget` command.

For example:

```
zadd ordered 1 1, 2 2
hmset objects 1 "{ 'id': 1 }", 2 "{ 'id': 2 }"
```

Then, in order to get a page from 0 to 10 first objects:

```
zrange ordered 0 10
```

And once you've already got ordered object identifiers:

```
hmget objects 1 2
```